# Half Size for CSS Sprite

Tags: css

I have a CSS sprite which shows country flags in 32px vertically stacked.

I am trying to reduce the size to 16px with this code but the flag is not reduced to 16px. What could be wrong here?

```css
.flag {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  line-height: 16px;
  background-size: 50% 50%;
  background: url(../images/flags.png) no-repeat;
}

.it {
  background-position: 0 -1920px;
}
```

```html
<span class="flag it"></span>
```

Comment: Place `background-size` rule after `background` shorthand rule

Comment: that does something but there has to be another problem, because i don't see anything on the screen. I tried to also halve the background-position for class '.it'

Comment: Can u provide a demo (jsfiddle or codepen)? that I can see the flags images.

Comment: Here is the flags file and how it looks. I deleted flags I didn't use to keep the filesize down so there will be some blank spaces in case you are wondering. https://ibb.co/mzWaQk

Comment: See DaniP's answer. You only need to change `background-size:50%` to `background-size:100%`. [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/kngms061/)

Comment: ok great that works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your actual problem in addition to the order on the properties is you think `%` on background-size will scale the original size of the image but the property doesn't work that way, it is relative to the container so you actually need to set it to be `100%` of the container:

```css
.flag {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  line-height: 50px;
  background: url('http://placehold.it/200x400/fcf?text=MIDDLE') no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}

.it {
  background-position: 0 -100px;
}
```

```html
<span class="flag"></span>
<span class="flag it"></span>
<h3>Original Image size</h3>
<img src="http://placehold.it/200x400/fcf?text=MIDDLE"/>
```

Remember you also need to change the values you have before for the background position and reset to the `16px` relation.

<sub>**Note:** I have used different dimensions just to make more clear the example scaling from 200 to 100.</sub>

Comment: Glad to help U @JoannaMikalai